# 2nd Condition or mixing 2nd and 3rd for assumption time in the past

Tags: conditionals, subjunctive-mood, conditional-perfect, apodosis

Which of the two following sentences would be better to use for a situation where I regret that I did not do something in the past?

1. If it were yesterday, I would buy the car.
2. If it were yesterday, I would have bought the car.

I’m confused about the action *I buy the car* didn’t happen in the past (*yesterday*), so I think mixing 2nd and 3rd conditionals for this situation is correct. But my friend said it might be 2nd conditional.

Should I use the 2nd conditional or a mixed one for this case?

**Edit**: My "It" means "now" here.

Comment: you need to clear things up. I don't get what you're trying to convey. please rephrase.

Comment: 1. If it were yesterday [at this moment], I would buy the car. However, I've missed my chance. // 2'. Had it been yesterday [when I received the $30 000], I would have bought the car.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I only wonder what the sentence is correct.

Comment: They're both correct but mean different things as explained by Edwin (essentially, it depends on what "it" refers to). So we can't tell you which is correct for your situation unless you tell us what you want it (or "it") to mean.

Comment: @Rupe My situation is: "I'm talking with my friend and just want to tell him about the car only". And I appreciate if you could tell me what different in meaning between two about sentence? I though they describe the same thing.

Comment: The difference is in what "it" means. It could just be a placeholder for "now", or it could be referring to some event and saying "if *that* had happened yesterday". See Edwin's examples.

Comment: So the answer is I'm wrong here. "It" means now, then I have to use 2nd condition, not mixing.

Comment: No, if *"it"* means now, then a mixed conditional is fine. If *"it"* means something else, then you might need a 2nd conditional.

Comment: @PerterShor I've edited my question. Sorry for my bad describable. Could you write you comment as a complete answer, so I can mark it as right answer for another ones like me

Comment: Native speakers are not taught “numbered conditions”, which make no sense to us.

Comment: @tchrist I agree with you. But in my country, we've been taught "numbered conditions" since we were childs, then my friends mark "numbered conditions" as the most important point in our debate

Comment: Native English speakers don't usually use *"if it were yesterday"* for this situation, so I'm not entirely sure what people would say here. Either choice sounds okay to me.

Comment: Some possibilities: *If today/this was yesterday, I would buy the car. If today becomes my special day, I will buy the car. If today had been yesterday, I would have bought the car.*

Comment: [“It is clear that a division of conditionals into the zero, first, second, and third categories does not adequately reflect actual usage.”](http://clok.uclan.ac.uk/1531/1/elt.ccp101.full_1531.pdf) —from ***“If only it were true: the problem with the four conditionals”,*** Christian Jones and Daniel Waller, *ELT Journal* 65:1 pp 24–32 (2011), Oxford University Press,  doi: 10.1093/elt/ccp101.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Formal Written English

There are quite a few possible ways to join up conditionals using one or another past-tense form.  Here are just a few of them:

1. If it was yesterday, I bought the car.
2. If it was yesterday, I will have bought the car.
3. If it was yesterday, I must have bought the car.
4. If it were yesterday, I would buy the car.
5. If it were yesterday, I would have bought the car.
6. If it had been yesterday, I would have bought the car.

To express regret at not having done something in the past, then the consequent should be a perfect construction.  Therefore you need *have bought* in the second clause, and so only the last two are possible for the sense you looking for.

Some folks might prefer 6 over 5, so that there is a compound tense in both the first part of the conditional (fancy name: *protasis*) and in its consequent (fancy name: *apodosis*).

But there really is no difference between them, and no one could ever find an iota of meaning-shift by electing 5 over 6 or 6 over 5.

### Informal Written English

People don’t much talk precisely the way those are written above. That’s because in the speech of any register lower than that of true oratory (such as in a formal delivery from a preacher, a judge, or in olden days, a politician) native speakers will virtually always contract the auxiliaries.  They just don’t always choose the same ones to contract.

In normal conversation, that same sixfold set given above therefore runs more like this:

1. If it was yesterday, I bought the car.
2. If it was yesterday, I’ll have bought the car.

   If it was yesterday, I’ll’ve bought the car.
3. If it was yesterday, I must’ve bought the car.
4. If it were yesterday, I’d buy the car.
5. If it were yesterday, I’d have bought the car.

   If it were yesterday, I would’ve bought the car.

   If it were yesterday, I’d’ve bought the car.
6. If it’d been yesterday, I would’ve bought the car.

   If it’d been yesterday, I’d have bought the car.

   If it’d been yesterday, I’d’ve bought the car.

### Spoken English

Although I’m still using the accepted standard orthography for the contractions, you as a nonnative speaker should understand that the conventions of writing **do not** reflect the actual pronunciations.

Rather, actual pronunciations of ***-d’ve*** are nearly always rendered as unstressed `/də/` in speech.

You will sometimes see this reflected in [eye dialect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect) in reported conversation, such as *woulda/coulda/shoulda*,  or even *Ida*.

I don’t recommend that, however.

### Literary English

To swing the other direction towards a more formal or literary register, these possibilities exist:

1. If it was yesterday, I bought the car.
2. If it was yesterday, I will have bought the car.
3. If it was yesterday, I must have bought the car.
4. Were it yesterday, I would buy the car.
5. Were it yesterday, I would have bought the car.
6. Had it been yesterday, I would have bought the car.

Probably the most interesting thing about this third set is that **inversion and consequent *if*-deletion is possible only in the true hypotheticals alone**, not in the other situations.

Comment: “With Ida, I’da eyed her up; with Karen, love, just let it drop.”