# "Had somebody something"

Tags: grammaticality

I wonder if it's okay to use "had somebody something" to convey the meaning of "if somebody had something"?

For example:

- *"I would have laughed at him had he more facetious manners"*
- *"I would have laughed at him if he had more facetious manners"*

Comment: This is a good question b/c it appears to be an inverted conditional with a 'had had' situation which results in not only the 'if' being omitted and 'he had' being reversed (to 'had he') but also the first 'had' being omitted. Similar to this: 'I would've married him if he'd had more money.' Changed to this: 'I would've married him had he more money.' With no real change in meaning (??). Hmm, interesting. I would've probably added a time marker: 'I would've married him had he more money at the time.' I couldn't find this particular case; maybe it has a name… Welcome and best of luck.

Comment: It's grammatical (try searching the site for inversion) but it's formal, written English, and not the clearest way to express it. The specific example is ambiguous.

Comment: "Had I not [done that, something else] would not have happened" is still reasonably current. I think "had he **had** more facetious manners" is better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does “would not have been possible had I remained” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177784/what-does-would-not-have-been-possible-had-i-remained-mean) It's not clear why you have doubts about the expression, so if your doubts aren't covered by the answers, then tell us your specific problem.

Comment: As with Stuart, I think it's grammatical but not very idiomatic.

Comment: People who closed this as a duplicate didn't read it. It's about using "have" in the sense of "possess," not as a marker of the perfect.